# How to print document in PDFnet /PDFTron

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, pdftron, pdfnet

In a windows store app project , I have a `pdftron.PDF.PDFViewCtrl MyPDFViewCtrl`

I then have a button that when I tap, I call a method that should be used to print the document loaded to the `MyPDFViewCtrl`

I tried with something like this:

```
private void Print_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pdftron.PDF.PDFPrintManager MyPrintManager;
    MyPrintManager = pdftron.PDF.PDFPrintManager.GetInstance();
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader loader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Printing");
    MyPrintManager.SetResourceLoader(loader);
    MyPrintManager.UnRegisterForPrintingContract();
    MyPrintManager.AddStandardPrintOption(Windows.Graphics.Printing.StandardPrintTaskOptions.MediaSize);
    MyPrintManager.AddStandardPrintOption(Windows.Graphics.Printing.StandardPrintTaskOptions.Orientation);
    MyPrintManager.AddUserOptionPageRange();
    MyPrintManager.RegisterForPrintingContract(docpdf, docpdf.GetDocInfo().GetTitle());
}
```

But when I press the button nothing happens.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: have you consulted the documentation here [PdfTron Getting Started](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/docs/WinRT/html/edce5f3e-add3-4c1e-90c8-3d9dc00e8e9e.htm)

Comment: yes, but i might be doing something wrong

Comment: ok i was missing something like this
await Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();